# how is $m_1 m_2...m_i/m_1 m_2....m_{i+1}$ a vector space over $A/m_{i+1}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Please help me with this problem . The problem was used in one of the questions in my examination and I failed to understand.

Problem as follows:

> If $A$ is a commutative ring in which $m_1,\ldots,m_n$ are maximal ideals in $A$. 
>   Then if $m_1 m_2...m_i/m_1 m_2....m_{i+1}$ can be regarded as $A/m_{i+1}$ module , how can we treat $m_1 m_2...m_i/m_1 m_2....m_{i+1}$  as a vector space over $A/m_{i+1}$?

Waiting for some help..

Comment: Since $m_{i+1}$ is maximal, $A/m_{i+1}$ is a field, and the notions of $A/m_{i+1}$ module and $A/m_{i+1}$ vector space are actually the same, which makes the answer to your question trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that $A$ is commutative, and that you meant it to be an $A/\mathfrak{m}_{i+1}$-vector space.

Then $\mathfrak{m}_1\mathfrak{m}_2\cdots \mathfrak{m}_i/\mathfrak{m}_1\mathfrak{m}_2\cdots \mathfrak{m}_{i+1}$ is an $A$-module on which $\mathfrak{m}_{i+1}$ acts trivially, hence it is an $A/\mathfrak{m}_{i+1}$- module by defining the action to be 
$$ \bar{x}\cdot m=x\cdot m $$
where $\bar{x}\in A/\mathfrak{m}_{i+1}$, $x$ is a lift of $\bar{x}$ to $A$, and $m\in \mathfrak{m}_1\mathfrak{m}_2\cdots \mathfrak{m}_i/\mathfrak{m}_1\mathfrak{m}_2\cdots \mathfrak{m}_{i+1}$. This action is well-defined because $\mathfrak{m}_{i+1}$ acts trivially.

Finally, $A/\mathfrak{m}_{i+1}$ is a field since $\mathfrak{m}_{i+1}$ is a maximal ideal, hence an $A/\mathfrak{m}_{i+1}$-module is a vector space over this field.

Comment: Yes $A$ is a commutative ring. sorry for inconvienience ,i'll edit in question...

Comment: Thanks for the answer . but could you please explain me  how is $\mathfrak{m}_1\mathfrak{m}_2\cdots \mathfrak{m}_i/\mathfrak{m}_1\mathfrak{m}_2\cdots \mathfrak{m}_{i+1}$ an $A-$ module.

Comment: It's a quotient of $A$-modules. If $M$ is an $A$-module and $N$ an $A$-submodule of $M$, then the abelian group $M/N$ has an action of $A$ by $a\cdot (x+N)=ax+N$.